# How to merge multiple PDF files into a single file?

Tags: 18.04, software-recommendation, files, pdf

Is there any **software** or methods available to merge multiple PDF files into a single file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `pdftk`, in the `pdftk` package.

From the `man pdftk` page:

```
   If PDF is electronic paper, then pdftk is an electronic staple-remover, hole-punch, binder, secret-decoder-ring, and X-Ray-glasses.  Pdftk is a simple tool for doing everyday things with PDF documents.  Use it to:

   * Merge PDF Documents or Collate PDF Page Scans
   * Split PDF Pages into a New Document
   * Rotate PDF Documents or Pages
   * Decrypt Input as Necessary (Password Required)
   * Encrypt Output as Desired
   * Fill PDF Forms with X/FDF Data and/or Flatten Forms
   * Generate FDF Data Stencils from PDF Forms
   * Apply a Background Watermark or a Foreground Stamp
   * Report PDF Metrics, Bookmarks and Metadata
   * Add/Update PDF Bookmarks or Metadata
   * Attach Files to PDF Pages or the PDF Document
   * Unpack PDF Attachments
   * Burst a PDF Document into Single Pages
   * Uncompress and Re-Compress Page Streams
   * Repair Corrupted PDF (Where Possible)
```

Comment: [This stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507766/merge-convert-multiple-pdf-files-into-one-pdf) is much older and has many conflicting responses --> is `pdftk` the best, or is it not?